# I'm facing this issue when making react project build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, build, mern

I'm making my react project build but it showing this error. Can anyone elaborate this problem and how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
$ npm run build

> my-app1@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.74543541.css from Css Minimizer plugin
RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (9509257216) is greater than 2 GB
```

Comment: try commenting all css code and uncomment one by one or block of codes. You will get the line of code which causing the error.

Comment: Found similar issue here. Go through the solutions. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11957